# Cakephp using the returned array values

Tags: cakephp-2.1

I guess this should be smple, but I have been stuck at this for a while so I need help. I have a cakephp application and I am getting the following array:

```
chratSortedMean= array(
    'totalAucFourHour' => array(
        'Screening Visit-1 (scr)' => array(
            'MmttFourthHour' => array(
                'totalAucs' => array(
                    (int) 0 => (float) 0,
                    (int) 1 => (float) 220
                )
            )
        ),
        'Month12' => array(
            'MmttFourthHour' => array(
                'totalAucs' => array(
                    (int) 0 => (float) 263.25,
                    (int) 1 => (float) 16.25
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    'totalAucTwoHour' => array(
        'Day0' => array(
            'MmttSecondHour' => array(
                'totalAucs' => array(
                    (int) 0 => (float) 0,
                    (int) 1 => (float) 112.125
                )
            )
        ),
        'DayD2' => array(
            'MmttSecondHour' => array(
                'totalAucs' => array(
                    (int) 0 => (float) 97.375,
                    (int) 1 => (float) 4.5
                )
            )
        ),
        'Month3' => array(
            'MmttSecondHour' => array(
                'totalAucs' => array(
                    (int) 0 => (float) 8.53125,
                    (int) 1 => (float) 8.75
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I want to calculate the mean of the totalAucs values for each of the timepoints(Screening Visit-1 (scr) , Month12, Day0 etc.) separately for the totalAucFourHour and totalAucTwoHour individually.

So the result i want is somewhat in the following form:

```
'totalAucFourHour' => array(
        'Screening Visit-1 (scr)' => array(
            'MmttFourthHour' => array(
                'totalAucMean' => (float) 110
                )
            )
        ),
                'Month12' => array(
            'MmttFourthHour' => array(
                'totalAucMean' => (float) 139.75

                )
            )
        )
    ),
```

and so on. I do not want to use multiple for loops as i expect the data to grow in the future.

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP has Core Utility Classes one of which is named [Set](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/set). Set is the array manipulation 
 Class. You can call it from anywhere in your app with:

```
Set::methodNane();
```

What you need are the [`extract();`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html#Set%3a%3aextract) or [`classicExtract();`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html#Set%3a%3aclassicExtract) methods. Usage is fairly simple:

```
$Day0path = '/chratSortedMean/totalAucTwoHour/Day0/MmttSecondHour'
$arrayOfDay0s = Set::extract($Day0path, $data);
```

Check the other possibilities at the [Cake Book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html). Also since CakePHP 2.2 there is a new array manipulation class [Hash](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html) and it is faster. Since that version Set is actually deprecated but [it will not be removed up until Cake 3.0](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/lorenzo/2012/07/01/cakephp_2_2_and_2_1_4_released).